# jq how to retain the parent square bracket while extracting and modifying content in json

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have the below JSON where I need modify few elements values and also extract only the contents inside containerDefinitions while retaining the square bracket.

The below script works in replacing the required value and extract the json inside the square brack inside containerDefinitions but leaves out the square bracket. Is there additinal command that can retain the square brackets.

```
echo $TASK_DEFINITION | jq '.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0] | ( .environment[] |= if   .name == "SMT_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" then .value = "myvalue" elif .name == "SERVER_API_TIMEOUT_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CANCEL_REQUEST" then .value = "myvalue" else . end) | .logConfiguration.options."awslogs-group" = "myvalue" ' > ${TASK_DEFINITION_PATH}/${SERVICE_NAME}2-task-definition.json
```

Input JSON

```
{
   "taskDefinition":{
      "taskDefinitionArn":"some value",
      "containerDefinitions":[
         {
            "name":"common-api-img",
            "environment":[
               {
                  "name":"SERVER_API_TIMEOUT_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CANCEL_REQUEST",
                  "value":"false"
               },
               {
                  "name":"SMT_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR",
                  "value":"valueToReplace"
               }
            ],
            "mountPoints":[
               
            ],
            "volumesFrom":[
               
            ]
         }
      ],
      "revision":65,
      "volumes":[
         
      ],
      "status":"ACTIVE"
   }
}
```

expected output

```
[
   {
      "name":"common-api-img",
      "environment":[
         {
            "name":"SERVER_API_TIMEOUT_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CANCEL_REQUEST",
            "value":"myvalue"
         },
         {
            "name":"SMT_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR",
            "value":"myvalue"
         }
      ],
      "mountPoints":[
         
      ],
      "volumesFrom":[
         
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: It would be helpful to also include your _actual output_, not just the expected output, so they can be compared just by reading the question.

Comment: BTW, if `echo $TASK_DEFINITION` isn't changed to `echo "$TASK_DEFINITION"` _with the quotes_, you get the bugs described in [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: (You might also want to avoid all-caps names for your own variables -- these are defined by POSIX to be used for variables meaningful to the shell and OS itself, whereas POSIX-compliant tools are guaranteed not to have their behavior modified by updates to variables with at least one lower-case character in their names; read https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html keeping in mind that modifying a regular shell variable overwrites any environment variable by the same name).

Comment: (the above is why it's safe to write `for path in ...` in bash, but not to write `for PATH in ...` -- only all-caps variables having side effects on shell behavior).

Answer (score 0):

When you put a `[0]` into your query, you're throwing away all but the first list entry. Thus, you no longer have a list. Thus, there are no more square brackets.

If you want to process *all* items, not just the first one (and thus to generate a stream of items), and want to put that stream into a list, you might instead want:

```
jq '
  .taskDefinition.containerDefinitions | map(
    ( .environment[] |=
      if .name == "SMT_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" then
        .value = "myvalue"
      elif .name == "SERVER_API_TIMEOUT_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CANCEL_REQUEST" then
        .value = "myvalue"
      else . end
    ) |
    .logConfiguration.options."awslogs-group" = "myvalue"
  )
'  <<<"$TASK_DEFINITIONS" >"${TASK_DEFINITION_PATH}/${SERVICE_NAME}2-task-definition.json"
```

Note the removal of `[0]`, and the use of `map()` to pass all the list elements through the transforming function.

---

Another approach is to use `jq -n`, and put `inputs` inside of a list:

```sh
jq -n '
  [ inputs |
    .taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[] |
    ( .environment[] |=
      if .name == "SMT_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" then
        .value = "myvalue"
      elif .name == "SERVER_API_TIMEOUT_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CANCEL_REQUEST" then
        .value = "myvalue"
      else . end
    ) |
    .logConfiguration.options."awslogs-group" = "myvalue"
  ]
'  <<<"$TASK_DEFINITIONS" >"${TASK_DEFINITION_PATH}/${SERVICE_NAME}2-task-definition.json"
```

Note the addition of outer `[` and `]`s, the use of `inputs` inside that block, the use of the `-n` argument to `jq`, and the use of `[]` where `[0]` had been used before.

Answer (score 0):

Your jq program adds .logConfiguration whereas the "expected output" does not, but except for that key, the following variation of your jq program retains the `[0]` and produces the "expected output":

```
[.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0]
 | ( .environment[] |= if .name | IN("SMT_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR", "SERVER_API_TIMEOUT_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CANCEL_REQUEST")
                       then .value = "myvalue" else . end)
 | .logConfiguration.options."awslogs-group" = "myvalue"
]
```

Comments:

1. Notice how the use of `IN/1` makes the solution much DRYer.
2. If your jq does not have `IN/1`, then now would be a good time to upgrade, but an alternative would be simply to include its `def`, as shown below.
3. If you opt for a solution that avoids `[0]` (e.g. in favor of `map`), you could still use `IN` to avoid redundancy.

---

```
def IN(s): first((s == .) // empty) // false;
```